# JavaScript Resource Planning Component / Gantt Chart with Editing Capabilities

Tags: javascript, html, gantt-chart

I'm looking for a JS-based Resource Planning Component, where i have the available resources on the left and the resource load on the right.

[image]

So far i only found a few gantt chart implementation, which lack add, move and editing capabilitys. I wounder whether such a component exists.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any out of the box solutions, but this is something that could probably be implemented somewhat easily. If you create several `div`s for rows, and then sub-`div`s for resources, you could build something like the spec.

1. First, keep track of all the resources, and the durations, in some kind of a datastructure.

   - I'd probably use backbone JS's models, since that's what I use for most everything.
2. Create a `render` function, that places an array of resources on the page, and lays them out, etc.
3. Create add/remove functions that add/remove elements, then call the `render` function to relayout the elements
4. To add dragging, I'd use [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), this makes it fairly easy to drag elements, and includes places for attaching callbacks when elements are dragged, dropped, etc.

   - This may take some doing, as dragging the duration of the events/resources may not be perfectly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quite nice library called DHTMLX Scheduler which also includes a timeline view:
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml
You can get the free GNU GPL version or a commercial one. A running example can be found here:  http://booking.javaplanner.com/

Comment: The demo on booking.javaplaner.com is currently unavailable, there is another one
http://scheduler-net.com/demo_multisource.aspx
In fact, the scheduler-net site promotes an another component, which is based on dhtmlxScheduler. But the demos shows common functionality.

Disclaimor: I work for DHTMLX.

Comment: Great component. I would recommend as well. We are using in at https://ganttpro.com as the core component to build our own online gantt chart software

Answer (score 1):

I found http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsrmt/ but it is GPL licensed. I am curious to hear, if you found anything else meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I have found lots of js gantt tools, but they all have performance isuues with 1000+ tasks.

This one works best http://www.bryntum.com/products/gantt/, but it's quite expensive.